# Creating a dynamic array of characters using C with pointers to pointers

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks, malloc, valgrind

I'm trying to create an array of pointers to pointers, at least to my understanding. But I'm getting invalid reads and writes with valgrind running.

```
char **format_file(FILE *infile) {
     char **char_array = malloc(20 * sizeof(char*));
     int c;
     int cUsed = 0;

     while ((c = fgetc(infile)) != EOF) {
         char_array[cUsed] = c;
         cUsed += 1;
     }

     printf("%s", *char_array);
     return char_array;
}
```

The code works by reading from an already opened file "infile". First I allocated memory for 20 characters with `malloc`, then I'm trying to read the file character by character into the allocated memory array until `EO`F is reached. However, valgrind's output is as follows when I make the code:

```
==7379== Invalid read of size 1
==7379==    at 0x4E7CB36: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1597)
==7379==    by 0x4E85198: printf (printf.c:35)
==7379==    by 0x400755: format_file (formatter.c:27)
==7379==    by 0x4006C1: main (format265alt.c:21)
==7379==  Address 0x6f is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Line 27 is the `printf` command that valgrind refers to as an invalid read of size 1.

formatter.c is the file containing the `format_file` function, while format265alt.c is a file that calls the formatter.c function and opens the file to be read.

I'm confused by the syntax of **, that is, how do I access and read/write the allocated memory?

I apologize if I have not provided enough information about this problem.

Comment: `char_array[cUsed]` is of type `char *` but `c` is of type `int`. See a problem there?

Comment: Right, but even if I cast c to be a character it still doesn't work.

Comment: Why would you cast it? Casting is not magic. Don't do it unless you know what you are doing. The point is that your types are wrong. Fix that properly (and no, casting isn't the way).

Comment: Don't use a cast unless you exsactly know why and will solve your problem! And why do you expect code which generates warnings to work?

Comment: Ok, I guess I've misunderstood what casting does exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`valgrind` complains because you are storing characters beyond the end of the allocated object.  The compiler should complain that you are storing characters into an object of the wrong type, use `-Wall -W` to enable useful warnings.

A `char **` is a pointer to a char pointer, it can point to an array of char pointers, also known as an array of strings.  You must allocate the array and each of the strings with the appropriate size for the file contents.

Here there are 2 possibilities:

- the function can either load the whole file into a single string, but there would be no need to return a pointer to a `char*`, just returning the string (`char *`) would suffice.
- the proposed API is more appropriate if the function is to return a pointer to an array of strings, one per line, with an extra `NULL` at the end, just like the `argv` array passed as the second argument to the `main` function.

For this, you must reallocate the string array as more lines are read from the `FILE*` and each line should be reallocated as it grows. Add a `NULL` pointer at the end of the string array to indicate its end.

Here is a very inefficient way to do this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char **format_file(FILE *infile) {
      size_t lines = 0;
      char **array = malloc(1 * sizeof(char*));
      size_t pos = 0;
      char *line = malloc(1);
      int c;

      while ((c = getc(infile)) != EOF) {
          if (c == '\n') {
              line[pos] = '\0';
              array = realloc(array, (lines + 2) * sizeof(char *));
              array[lines++] = line;
              line = malloc(1);
              pos = 0;
              continue;
          }
          line = realloc(line, pos + 2);
          line[pos++] = c;
    }
    if (pos > 0) {
        line[pos] = '\0';
        array = realloc(array, (lines + 2) * sizeof(char *));
        array[lines++] = line;
    } else {
        free(line);
    }
    array[lines] = NULL;
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just creating an array of characters, a one-dimensional character array is sufficient. No need for the `char**` business. However, make sure you null terminate the array if you are trying to use it as a string.

Comment: So just have to add '\0' at the end? C won't do this automatically?

Comment: Correct. C will in general not do anything for you. The general mantra is that "the programmer is always right", which can lead to various bugs/segmentation faults if you're not careful.

Comment: @th13 The philosophy of C & C++ is "the programmer is in charge" and this is what make C & C++ so interesting and challenging languages. That's the reason why I don't like Java and not so much but also C#.